# Creating a Webhook Receiver in Laravel using GET Method for Zoho Sign

Tags: get, webhooks, laravel-9, zoho

I'm working on integrating Zoho Sign into my Laravel application, and I need to set up a webhook receiver to get the completed documents from Zoho Sign. However, Zoho Sign's webhook system only accepts GET requests.

I've successfully implemented webhook receivers in Laravel before, but they typically use POST requests. I'm not sure how to handle GET requests for webhook endpoints in Laravel.

Could someone please provide guidance or a code example on how to create a webhook receiver in Laravel that listens to GET requests from Zoho Sign? Specifically, I need to capture the webhook data sent by Zoho Sign and process it within my Laravel application.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I created a new route in web_api.php like this:

`Route::get('receive-waiver', [WaiverController::class, 'ReceiveWaiver']);`

2. I created a "WaiverController" with a function of ReceiveWaiver.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Zoho;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class WaiverController extends Controller
{

    public function ReceiveWaiver(Request $request)
    {
        \Log::info('Webhook success!');
        \Log::info('Webhook Data: ' . json_encode($request['requests']));
        \Log::info('Webhook Document: ' . json_encode($request['requests']['document_ids']));
        try {

            if (!empty($request['requests'])) {
                $waiverData = json_encode($request['requests']);
                $waiverDocument = json_encode($request['requests']['document_ids']);
                \Log::info('Success Webhook Data: ' . $waiverData);
                \Log::info('Success Webhook Document: ' . $waiverDocument);

            }

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Webhook received'], true);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
            \Log::info('Error Webhooks: ' . $errorMessage);
            return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
}
```

And in Zoho Sign, this is what it looks like.

[Zoho Sign Webhook Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEb0F.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Zoho Sign's webhook system only accepts GET requests.

No, Zoho Sign makes **POST** request to the webhook URL you provide in the setup page. The request payload (request body) will contain the data related to the event that happens.

So, you can continue developing like you were doing before. You can do it with the POST route in your application.

```php
Route::post('receive-waiver', [WaiverController::class, 'ReceiveWaiver']);
```

```php
public function ReceiveWaiver(Request $request) {
   \Log::info('Webhook success!');
   $requestContent = $request->getContent();
   \Log::info('Webhook Data: ' . $requestContent);
   return response()->status(200);
}
```

You can take these below links as references:

https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/webhooks-for-zoho-sign

https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/zoho-sign/admin-guide/webhooks/articles/webhooks-management#Zoho_Sign_Webhooks

Comment: Also, don't forget to add the route to csrf exclude list.

Comment: Making the route into POST isn't working in Zoho Sign Webhook. The Result is always: FAILURE.

Comment: Also, I already excluded my route "receive-waiver" into the csrf exclude list

Comment: Updated the answer.​ Do you get any errors on Laravel logs? Just have an empty response as of now and test it on Zoho Sign. When the result is SUCCESS, then we can proceed further.

Comment: Keeping the route as POST itself.

Comment: There are no laravel logs or even error laravel logs. I have no other fix method/s just to keep the route as POST and become Success on Zoho Sign's Webhook

Comment: Is that SUCCESS now? after defining it as POST? Awesome then, line by line try adding your logic there and test with the sample request data mentioned in the document.

Comment: Oh sorry. I got you confused and I gave misinfo.

If I keep the route into GET, the Zoho Sign's Webhook become success. And if I keep the route into POST, the Zoho SIgn's Webhook become failure.

Maybe Zoho Sign's Webhook has a requirement that does not accept simple POST Method route?

Comment: Right now I removed the auth middleware and still using the GET Method. The Laravel can listen now to the webhook. However in the logs, $request->all() is null. With this, I tried the POST Method without the middleware, the laravel does not listen to the webhook. Only GET Method.

Comment: I tried it on POSTMAN first, and it seems like the problem is inside Laravel.

Comment: I am using now this route: Route::post('receive-waiver', [WaiverController::class, 'ReceiveWaiver']);

route:cache
route:clear

And the error says:
The GET method is not supported for route api/receive-waiver. Supported methods: POST

I am already using POST yet the error says GET method not supported